# Local notification ,time setting

Tags: iphone

HI All,

i am trying to use local notification
by using this

```
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[dateComps setDay: [dateComponents day]];
[dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];  // Notification will fire in one minute

[dateComps setMinute:0 ];   //[timeComponents minute]];
[dateComps setSecond:60];   //[timeComponents second]];
```

and i hv string something like current time :  2011-03-26 11:59:31 GMT
according to which i need to set sec,min, hours.

How can i set min, week,month, year etc, to pop up notification in above condition??

Guidenece needed.

Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a NSDateComponent from the above date as

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(kCFCalendarUnitHour | kCFCalendarUnitMinute | kCFCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:date];

NSInteger hour = [components hour];

NSInteger minute = [components minute];

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set sec,min,hours etc. with this string "current time : 2011-03-26 11:59:31 GMT"

then first make a NSDate with this string using NSDateFormatter and get your values from this date.

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2011-03-26 11:59:31";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];  
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: i m getting current time, np with dat, i just want to break this formst, like  sec, min, hour seperately and put into another varable.